What causes a delay in starting the execution, or not responding at all, when "Run" is clicked on an Excel Office Script?
It is quite often that when I click Run for an Excel Office Script it will not start executing or delay starting to run for more than a few seconds. The scripts are only about 200 lines.
I was expecting the scripts to start running immediately when I click Run. Even when I go into the Editor for the script and see it is loaded there, it still may not run immediately when Run is clicked.

Did you run the script on local installed Excel application or online Excel?

I'm running the scripts in a locally installed Excel application.

Please test it on Excel Online first. If there is no delay, it indicates that your internet connection might be the issue. The OfficeScripts are stored on OneDrive whether you run them on the local application or in the cloud.

We also have trouble with executing scripts. See also * https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1154304/office-script-not-running-on-button-click

Excel - TypeScript executes slow from button, fast from script editor

Our observations are

buttons work the least reliable
most reliable is the run button at the top of the edit box.
the scripts need to be compiled; this seems to require an internet connection
sometimes, especially if you create a new script or rename it, restarting Excel might help.
adding the script to the workbook might help, as then it is not loaded from OneDrive anymore.
there seems to be no difference between Excel for the web and native Excel.

